# Grub fails to install on custom USB iso

Tags: grub2, usb-drive, remastersys, custom-distributions

I'm trying to create a custom iso of an Ubuntu install - that way, I can install a bunch of educational programs & plugins on one computer and they'll automatically be on every computer I install the iso on.

What I'm doing right now is using remastersys to create a distributable version of Ubuntu. It creates the iso, but I can't burn to a CD (the file is 1.1gb) and the computers in question don't have DVD drives. So I tried putting the iso onto a USB instead via the included Startup Disk Creator. It boots and installs fine for the most part, but at the very end of the installation, it tells me that it can't install Grub.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Or, alternately, is there a tool other than remastersys that you'd suggest using for creating a distributable iso?

Comment: Are you sure its not a remastersys issue, as it is no longer developed and has been forked to relinux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) may help you. Check my related [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33984/) about a similar question:

*Its a tool that scans your APT-installed packages and build a list for you. You can then manually select/deselect the ones you want, save the list, and it can even download/use cache to save selected packages in a CD/folder (for an offline automatic install of currently installed apps)*

I know, this is not *exactly* what you want. But you could customize your CD install to use the .DEB files folder created by APTonCD as an additional APT-GET source list (like an offline PPA) by creating a customized entry in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

And then just create a simple post-install script to install all the packages there.

So, if your "*remastered install with pre-installed additional packages*" is not working, maybe this "*original install with post-install trigger to apt-get packages in a folder*" approach may work.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a possibility. Overall, it might be easier than trying to fiddle with the custom iso. If I don't get any direct solutions, I'll do this for sure.

Comment: After trying this out, it works perfectly. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Youre welcome, im glad it worked and solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is my solution:

Before you remaster install grub on the system to be remastered. Somehow grub is not installed. grub-pc is installed. Install grub from synaptic. This will replace grub-pc.

Now remaster your system.  It should work without a problem after this.